# How can I set the Lamp type using Python scripting?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to set the Lamp type using Python scripting. I've got the Lamp object:

```
Lamp = bpy.data.objects["Lamp"]
```

But `Lamp.type` seems read-only. How can I set it without creating a new lamp?

Comment: I'll assume you're using blender 2.7x get the lamp from `bpy.data.lamps` not objects then be sure to set it with caps('HEMI', 'AREA', 'SPOT', etc). Also i wouldn't recommend using Lamp as a name since it is a named structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Confusion between object and its data**

Blender has many object types, 'LAMP' is one of them. It is set by the data type on creation and is read only.

```
>>> D.objects['Lamp']
bpy.data.objects['Lamp']

>>> D.objects['Lamp'].type
'LAMP'

>>> D.objects['Lamp'].type = 'LAMP'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "type" from "Object" is read-only
```

A `'LAMP'` type object (`bpy.data.objects`) has a lamp (`bpy.data.lamps`) object as its data. Just like a `'MESH'` object has a mesh (`bpy.data.meshes`)  The type of lamp can be set on the data part.

```
>>> D.objects['Lamp'].data
bpy.data.lamps['Lamp']

>>> lamp = D.objects['Lamp'].data
>>> lamp.type
'SPOT'

>>> lamp.type = 'HEMI'
>>> lamp.type
'HEMI'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not read only. Try:

```
Lamp = bpy.data.objects["Lamp"]
Lamp.location = (0, -2, 3.7)
```